# How to set attribute in adf default search form query

Tags: java, search, oracle11g, oracle-adf

I am using the default search form in `Jdeveloper 11.1.2.3`  `ADF` Query with Table. The search form simply allows the user to input the searching values for the Queryable attributes and then execute the default searching on the `ViewObject`

I follow this blog to override the default query:

[How-to tell the ViewCriteria a user chose in an af:query component](https://blogs.oracle.com/jdevotnharvest/entry/how-to_tell_the_viewcriteria_a_user_chose_in_an_afquery_component)

Question is how to set the value of some attributes in the query. The user will add what ever he/she want to the search form and those are captured in `queryEvent` I want to add the value of some attributes which are not shown to the user and it is required for the query to execute correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer in the following link:

[How to set attribute in ADF default search form query. OTN Community](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3541989)

Note: The link in the question is very useful and should be used a long with the proposed answer in the link mention above